# Home folder not shown in "Finder"

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I am trying to setup a MacBook Air I bought from work, and I noticed that my home folder

```
/Users/alex
```

is not shown in "Finder":

[image]

What the heck is going on? Why is my hole folder not shown in "Finder", and how to fix this bug?

Comment: What are the permissions of /Users ? Check with `ls -ld /Users`.

Comment: You don't have "Shared", either. Probably best to erase the volume and reinstall the OS, to make sure there's no work-configured stuff remaining.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x root admin`

Comment: I probably removed "shared" already (and other crap)

Comment: Don't do that. It has important uses. Also Applications and Library are both Zero Bytes?

Comment: yes seems so that Applications has zero bytes

Comment: As said, I'd erase and reinstall the OS, as something's gone very weird with this installation -- either something work did, or something you've done by removing 'crap'.

Comment: I will not / I cannot reinstall the OS. It has been just installed brand new on the computer.

Comment: A brand new install should not have these problems. It's also weird that the Modified date is showing 24 August. Are you sure that the Mac is booting from the internal, and that your User account isn't actually on some other volume?

Comment: Yes, there is only the internal hard drive. Also keep in mind: Its a mac. It is error-prone. I would have wondered if things went smoothly. Did take about 1 hour to create an Apple ID. 
My user account is on the same volume. The other volumes you see there are just external drives just with data. Maybe there are bugs in version 13.0.1...

Comment: Are there actually any apps in /Applications? If you right-click on something like Preview or Safari in the Dock, and click on Options > Show in Finder, what's the path of that window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141269/discussion-between-alex-and-benwiggy).

Answer (score 3):

Something seems very wrong with this installation. You claim your company's IT department installed it today -- I would suggest that they've done something very strange.

I strongly recommend erasing and reinstalling the OS. Apple Support pages for erasing and reinstalling the OS are here:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl7676b710/13.0/mac/13.0
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1599/13.0/mac/13.0